# How to find the number of combinations of $x,y,z$ that satisfy an equation

Tags: combinatorics

The equation is $x + y + z = 18$,
with the constraints:

$2 \leq x \leq 8$

$1 \leq y \leq 7$

$1 \leq z \leq 6 $

First I solved it so the lower bounds where zero, by substituting the following:

$x' = x - 2$, $y' = y - 1$, $z'= z - 1$.

Which gave me the combination of $16,2 = 120$, now I have to subtract the number of combination of $x,y,z$ that are over, so $x'\geq7$, $y'\geq7$, or $z'\geq6$. The problem is when I plug those into the equation I end up with a negative answer and do not know how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you need to count the solutions in non-negative integers to $x'+y'+z'=14$ that violate at least one of the constraints $x'\le 6$, $y'\le 6$, and $z'\le 5$. This is an [inclusion-exclusion argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

First count the solutions with $x'\ge 7$. That’s the number of solutions in non-negative integers to $x''+y'+z'=7$, where $x''=x'-7$. You know how to compute this: it’s $$\binom{7+3-1}{3-1}=\binom92=36\;.$$

Similarly, you find that there are $\dbinom92=36$ solutions with $y'\ge 7$ and $\dbinom{10}2=45$ with $z'\ge 5$. These all have to be subtracted from $120$, leaving $120-36-36-45=3$ valid solutions.

However, some invalid solutions were removed twice, because they violated two constraints; these must be added back in once.

- How many solutions to $x'+y'+z'=14$ have $x'\ge 7$ **and** $y'\ge 7$?
- How many have $x'\ge 7$ **and** $z'\ge 6$?
- How many have $y'\ge 7$ **and** $z'\ge 6$?

All of those must be added back in. If there were any solutions that violated all three constraints, they would now have been counted once in the $120$, subtracted $3$ times in the initial correction, and added back in $3$ times in the second correction, so they would be included in the total and would need to be subtracted. However, there are none, so no further correction is needed.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Your answer will be equal to the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $$(x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots +x^{8})(x+x^{2}+\cdots +x^{7})(x+x^{2}+\cdots +x^{6})$$

Which is equal to the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $$(1+x+\cdots +x^{6})(1+x+\cdots +x^{6})(1+x+x^{2}+\cdots x^{5})=(1-x^{7})^{2}(1-x^{6})(1-x)^{-3}$$

Comment: Generating functions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since $x+y \leq 8+7 = 15$ we must have $z \geq 3$ while $x+y \geq 2+1 = 3$ tells us that $z \leq 15$

Do something similar to establish bounds for $x$ and $y$ and compare to the originally set bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force yields the following 10 combinations:
$$
(8,4,6),(7,5,6),(6,6,6),(5,7,6), \\
(8,5,5),(7,6,5),(6,7,5), \\
(8,6,4),(7,7,4),\\
(8,7,3) \\
$$

Comment: Now do this for numbers in the thousands, or higher… This is not teacher understanding in any way.

Comment: That's true. The typical way to solve this is through principle of inclusion-exclusion or generating functions. I figured I would put this here anyways just to check your answer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: as $x' = x-2$, it follows that $x' \leq 6$ rather than $x' \leq 8$. Similar for $y'$ and $z'$.